# How to supplement the details to prove $\frac{c}{2}<x_n<0$?

Tags: analysis, proof-writing

Although I understand the idea of complete induction and how it works, I am not sure how to refine the proof process.

For example:
let $x_1 = \frac{c}{2}$, where $c$ is some constant. Define
$$x_{n+1}=\frac{c}{2}+\frac{x_n^2}{2},\quad n=1,2,\cdots.$$
When $-4<c<0$,$$x_1=\frac{c}{2}<0,$$
$$\frac{c}{2}<x_2=\frac{c}{2}+\frac{x_1^2}{2}=\frac{c}{2}+\frac{c^2}{8}<
0,$$
$$\frac{c}{2}<x_3=\frac{c}{2}+\frac{x_2^2}{2}<\frac{c}{2}+\frac{c^2}{8}<
0,$$
$$\cdots\cdots$$
It is not difficult to prove by complete induction that:
$$\frac{c}{2}<x_n<0,\quad n=2,3,\cdots
$$

But I don't know how to write out the proof details. How to supplement the proof details of this complete induction? This confuses me.